# OrientDB Duplicate Vetex

Tags: indexing, duplicates, unique, orientdb

I have used the UNIQUE parameter, to avoid having duplicate entries, as follows:

```
  Parameter<String, String> parameter = new Parameter<String, String>("type", "UNIQUE"); 
  g.createKeyIndex("name", Vertex.class,parameter);
```

However, I couldn't get rid of the exception I have:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.ORecordDuplicatedException: Cannot index record . . . .
```

based on the information I could found, I should set "skipDuplicates" to true. However, I didn't find how or where to set this in java. I wrote a solution by my self but it is somehow very slow (30 Million relationships are stored in 2.5 hours).

Any hints how to set the "skipDuplicates" in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this way to tackle the exception:

```
                        try{
                              v = g.addVertex(null, "name", vertexA);
                          }catch(ORecordDuplicatedException oe){
                             System.out.println("Exception> "+oe.getRid() );
                          }
```

is there better answer ?

Comment: I think it is the best solution